# What do I need to do and learn to send information over lan?

Tags: client, lan

Sorry for the open-ended question here, but I really had no idea what exactly to ask for.

Im looking to communicate between two machines, one running windows, one running Linino, over a wi-fi network. What is the general process of writing the server and client code? What language would each need to use and what libraries/ classes would I need to familiarize myself with?

I know I'm basically asking how the internet works, but I sort of need somewhere to start.

(I'm sending mjpgs one way and sending raw bytes the other way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The programmer's interface to the network is sockets, also called winsock in Windows. Pick your language: Most of them can do this. Sample code in many languages is easy to find. There is a C tutorial online if you search for the "Winsock Programmers FAQ".